# Permissions and roles stored in DB, rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, permissions, authorization, roles

In my app I want to implement roles and permissions in them in such way, that users admins can create new roles in their browsers. So I need permissions table and roles table, where every role is a combination of permissions. For now I used CanCan gem, but this behavior is not default for this gem and finally I got very complicated structure of roles and checking permissions. Can anybody tell me what gem provides this behavior or maybe I should make it without any gems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Abilities in Database](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Abilities-in-Database) and [Ability for Other Users](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-for-Other-Users) from the CanCan wiki:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can do |action, subject_class, subject|
      user.permissions.find_all_by_action(aliases_for_action(action)).any? do |permission|
        permission.subject_class == subject_class.to_s &&
          (subject.nil? || permission.subject_id.nil? || permission.subject_id == subject.id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT
Some load optimizations:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user, context = nil)
    if context.nil?
      can do |action, subject_class, subject|
        user.permissions.find_all_by_action(aliases_for_action(action)).any? do |permission|
          permission.subject_class == subject_class.to_s &&
           (subject.nil? || permission.subject_id.nil? || permission.subject_id == subject.id)
      end
    elsif context == :post
      can :manage, Post, :id => y
    elsif context == :users
      can :manage, User, :id => x
    end
  ...
```

And in controllers:

```
class UsersController
  protected
  def current_ability
    Ability.new(current_user, :users)

class PostsController
  protected
  def current_ability
    Ability.new(current_user, :posts)
```

Comment: Yes, I implemented it like this now, but it makes too much requests to DB when a page loading. I want to know is there any more suitable way to do this.

Comment: You may make the permissions table in-memory, or pass in to the ability constructor a second context variable, and depending on context eager load permissions based on context and define them using classical CanCan

Comment: I think that this is most simple way..should do it so. thanks